# Xcode refresh project after git checkout

Tags: xcode, git

I just started experimenting with git integration in Xcode and I can't seem to find a way to make Xcode reload the project file after a git checkout. Say I have two branches one stable branch containing files: 
 
a.cpp 
b.cpp 
And a unstable branch containing files:
a.cpp
b.cpp
c.cpp
If I start from the stable branch and checkout the unstable branch, the c.cpp file does not appear in the navigation bar, or in the compile sources in build phases. If I then close the project and reopen it, the project seems to load correctly and the c.cpp file shows up as expected. If I then checkout the stable branch again, the c.cpp file is deleted from the working copy, but the project is again not refreshed so it shows up as missing (red). And again, if I close and reopen the project the file is gone from the navigator as expected. It seems very strange to me that I have to close and reopen Xcode every time I checkout a git commit with a different project file. Is this how Xcode behaves or is this a bug on my instance (this would not be the first time software on my Mac behaves weird)

Comment: It isn't surprising that the project navigator has trouble updating / refreshing itself. Can you solve the problem a little less violently, e.g. by closing the project navigator and opening, or by switching to a different navigator and back to the project navigator?

Comment: Or maybe even just twisting the project triangle closed and opening it again.

Comment: I tried again, and this time I selected the project and clicked on Navigate > Reveal in Project Navigator, which refreshed the navigator correctly. After this the navigator started updating itself after checkouts...

Comment: So basically you slapped it and woke it up...!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

**Source Control** menu > **Refresh File Status**